# How can I integrate my TestNG tests with Selenium in TeamCity?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, teamcity, testng

Please guide me through the steps on setting up TeamCity so that it can run my TestNG tests.

**My Objective**: Whenever I run a new build on TeamCity, it should automatically trigger my testNG suite on the new build.

I am using the following tools:
**IDE**: Eclipse
**Automation Tool**: Selenium Webdriver
**Language**: Java
**Test Runner Framework**: TestNG

Any reference to link or website would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should integrate ANT in your selenium+TestNG framework so that you can run the tests from a build script. Plus, TeamCity's [docs](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Testing+Frameworks) say that

> **TeamCity directly supports the following testing frameworks**:
>
> JUnit and TestNG for the following runners: Ant (when tests are run by
>   the junit and testng tasks directly within the script)

Some links: 
[Apache ANT](http://ant.apache.org/)
[ANT Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheAnt/article.html)
[TestNG with ANT](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_plug_with_ant.htm)

So once you create your build script in `build.xml` file which should lie in your framework's root folder, you should configure your build job and add a build step (with an [ANT build runner](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Ant)) in TeamCity to run this build.xml after TeamCity finishes building/deploying the app. You can do that by specifying a step execution policy for the ANT build step.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Abhijeet, that was lightning quick. i will go through stated solution. Will provide update later.